# How can I declare an object property in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-stylesheet

[image]

This code snippet gives me this error:

> Type 'JustifyContent | undefined' is not assignable to type '"space-around" | "space-between" | "space-evenly" | "center" | "flex-end" | "flex-start" | undefined'.
> Type 'string & {}' is not assignable to type '"space-around" | "space-between" | "space-evenly" | "center" | "flex-end" | "flex-start" | undefined'.

I would like help to solve this.

Constructive criticism in writing the code is welcome.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! It would help if you posted your code as text in your question, rather than an image. Then we can easily copy/paste/update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use a type for CSS (on the web) in react native stylesheet. Thats not going to work. React native stylesheets are heavily inspired by Web based CSS, but they are a different thing.

Looking at the types, you want `FlexStyle['justifyContent']` from the `react-native` module.

A very simple example:

```
import { StyleSheet, FlexStyle } from 'react-native'

const justify: FlexStyle['justifyContent'] = 'center'

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  foo: {
    justifyContent: justify // works fine
  }
})
```

I'd give you a more complete example, but I'm not going to retype all the code from your image. None the less, this should give you the right type to use.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgZRgTwDYFNkAstYwA0cAYtgB6qZZwC+cAZlBCHAORRYCGAxjAFoAdtxjAAblnYAoabwhCAzvABWAV2XBGaAFxlK1bAG126zdoDCCmFiEx2AXTgBeDr1s2oMuQuVxlNIouKOjYeAQwAHS8XKJYABQI0nBMEBB6SSkpZmKW1h56OVpoyfTSdACUQA)